# Jquery- using <li> values as the source for jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, javascript-objects

trying to use a list of numbers as the source for the jquery ui autocomplete, but I'm having issues populating the data object from the list. Something along these lines :

```
  var data

  $('.numberList li').each(function (index) {
         data += [$(this).text()];
    });
```

and the source:

```
    $("#numberText").autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [push method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) instead of += to add items into an array; like this:

```
var data = [];
$('.numberList li').each(function (index) {
     data.push($(this).text());
});

$("#numberText").autocomplete({
    source: data
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: ah the 'ol Push method. Thanks for that :)